# Get the limited rows on date range from dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, dplyr, data.table

I am having this dataframe.

```
token    DD1                   Type         DD2         Price
AB-1     2018-01-01 10:12:15   Low          2018-01-25  10000
AB-5     2018-01-10 10:12:15   Low          2018-01-25  15000
AB-2     2018-01-05 12:25:04   High         2018-01-20  25000
AB-3     2018-01-03 17:04:25   Low          2018-01-27  50000
....
AB-8     2017-12-10 21:08:12   Low          2017-12-30  60000
AB-8     2017-12-10 21:08:12   High         2017-12-30  30000
```

dput:

```
structure(list(token = structure(c(2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 6L
), .Label = c("....", "AB-1", "AB-2", "AB-3", "AB-5", "AB-8"), class = "factor"), 
    DD1 = structure(c(2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("", 
    "01/01/2018 10:12:15", "03/01/2018 17:04:25", "05/01/2018 12:25:04", 
    "10/01/2018 10:12:15", "10/12/2017 21:08:12"), class = "factor"), 
    Type = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
    "High", "Low"), class = "factor"), DD2 = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("", "20/01/2018", "25/01/2018", 
    "27/01/2018", "30/12/2017"), class = "factor"), Price = c(10000L, 
    15000L, 25000L, 50000L, NA, 60000L, 30000L)), .Names = c("token", 
"DD1", "Type", "DD2", "Price"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

From the above mentioned dataframe I want 2 kind of sub set data frame based on date (last three date in descending order (from `DD2`) if row is not available for particular date than show that date with all fields as '0') and month (last three date in descending order if row is not available for particular date than show that date with all fields as '0').

Formula for Avg Low (same for Avg high): DD2-DD1 and than take Median as per nrow available.

% Formula For month: (Recent Value-Old Value)/(Old Vaule)

The code should pick last three days data as well as last three months data from dataframe whenever i run the code.

DF1:

```
Date        nrow for Low  Med Low sum of value low nrow for High  Med High sum of value High
27-01-2018  1             24      50000            0             0          0
26-01-2018  0             0       0                0             0          0
25-01-2018  2             19.5    25000            0             0          0
```

DF2

```
Month  nrow low    %    sum low     %    nrow high     %     sum high     % 
Jan-18 3         200%   75000     25%    1            0%     25000     -17%
Dec-17 1         100%   60000    100%    1          100%     0         100%
Nov-17 0          -     -        -       0           -       -         -
```

Comment: @ZahiroMor This is my desired output, not stored as Dataframe in R...:(

Comment: you will get more help if you can also show what you have tried so far and where exactly you are stuck

Comment: Without data difficult, but this could be one approach, using `dplyr`: You need a data frame with a column containing all days in a year. Left join this with your data frame, so that you can be sure that also the days without data get a row. You'll have to store your date files as date (use `lubridate`). Then you can easily `arrange` in descending order, `group_by` month, make new columns with `mutate` containing the calculation needed, and then `filter` take the (the first) 3 rows per month.

Comment: @ZahiroMor Updated the dput data.

Comment: @Tjebo I am trying using that method but couldn't done yet `DF1$Sum_low<-paste('USD ',formatC(sum(df[df1$TYPE=='Low' & 
                           & !(df$token%in% price$token)
                           ,]$price), big.mark=',', format = 'f',
                           digit=1))`

Comment: what are you exactly intending to calculate in your 'Avg' columns? In your question you are subtracting days. Do you intend to get the number of days? An interval?

Comment: @Tjebo i'm subtracting the date so that i can calculate the Average (i.e if for a particular day i have 10 rows in `DD2` than i can get the average time from `DD1` to `DD2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this Q already has an accepted answer, I felt challenged to provide an answer which uses `dcast()` and `melt()`. Any missing dates and months are completed using `CJ()` and joins as requested by the OP.

The code tries to reproduce OP's expected results as close as possible. The particular customisation is why the code looks so much convoluted.

If requested, I am willing to explain the code in more detail.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)

# daily
DF1 <- 
  DF[, .(n = .N, days = median(difftime(as.Date(DD2, "%d/%m/%Y"), 
                                        as.Date(DD1, "%d/%m/%Y"), units = "day")), 
         sum = sum(Price)), by = .(DD2, Type)][
           , Date := as.Date(DD2, "%d/%m/%Y")][
             , dcast(.SD, Date ~ Type, value.var = c("n", "days", "sum"), fill = 0)][
               .(Date = seq(max(Date), length.out = 3L, by = "-1 days")), on = "Date"][
                 , setcolorder(.SD, c(1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6))][
                   is.na(n_Low), (2:7) := lapply(.SD, function(x) 0), .SDcols = 2:7][]
DF1
```

> ```
>          Date n_Low  days_Low sum_Low n_High days_High sum_High
> 1: 2018-01-27     1 24.0 days   50000      0    0 days        0
> 2: 2018-01-26     0  0.0 days       0      0    0 days        0
> 3: 2018-01-25     2 19.5 days   25000      0    0 days        0
> ```

```
# monthly
DF2 <-
  DF[, Month := lubridate::floor_date(as.Date(DD2, "%d/%m/%Y"), unit = "month")][
    , .(n = .N, sum = sum(Price)), by = .(Month, Type)][
      CJ(Month = seq(max(Month), length.out = 3L, by = "-1 months"), Type = unique(Type)), 
      on = .(Month, Type)][
        , melt(.SD, id.vars = c("Month", "Type"))][
          is.na(value), value := 0][
            , Pct := {
              old <- shift(value); round(100 * ifelse(old == 0, 1, (value - old) / old))
            }, 
            by = .(variable, Type)][
              , dcast(.SD, Type + Month ~ variable, value.var = c("value", "Pct"))][
                , setnames(.SD, c("value_n", "value_sum"), c("n", "sum"))][
                  , dcast(.SD, Month ~ Type, value.var = c("n", "Pct_n", "sum", "Pct_sum"))][
                    order(-Month), setcolorder(.SD, c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8))]
DF2
```

> ```
>         Month n_Low Pct_n_Low sum_Low Pct_sum_Low n_High Pct_n_High sum_High Pct_sum_High
> 1: 2018-01-01     3       200   75000          25      1          0    25000          -17
> 2: 2017-12-01     1       100   60000         100      1        100    30000          100
> 3: 2017-11-01     0        NA       0          NA      0         NA        0           NA
> ```

Comment: Can i also get 4 additional column in DF2 2 for each `Low` and `High` which give me `Med for Low` and `Average` of sum or Low and high, respectively. For a particular month.

Comment: @ Uwe interesting. Unfortunately, as I am not using data.table, parts of this I could not offer with my answer. But yes. I also thought of using dcast but did not get my head around how to do that , and this looks indeed quite nice:)

Answer (score 1):

Does the following approach help?

```
require(tidyverse)
```

**Edit** 
This is a very convoluted approach and is most certainly possible to be solved more elegantly.

```
dat <- structure(list(token = structure(c(2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("....", "AB-1", "AB-2", "AB-3", "AB-5", "AB-8"), class = "character"), DD1 = structure(c(2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("", "01/01/2018 10:12:15", "03/01/2018 17:04:25", "05/01/2018 12:25:04", "10/01/2018 10:12:15", "10/12/2017 21:08:12"), class = "factor"),
Type = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("", "High", "Low"), class = "character"), DD2 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("", "20/01/2018", "25/01/2018", "27/01/2018", "30/12/2017"), class = "factor"), Price = c(10000L, 15000L, 25000L, 50000L, NA, 60000L, 30000L)), .Names = c("token", "DD1", "Type", "DD2", "Price"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
#I have included this into the code because structure(your output) had messed up a lot with factors   

dat <- dat[c(1:4,6:7),]
dat <- dat %>% mutate(DD1 = dmy_hms(DD1), DD2 = dmy(DD2), Type = as.character(Type))

dat_summary <- dat %>%  
 mutate(diff_days = round(as.duration(DD1%--%DD2)/ddays(1),0),
#uses lubridate  to calculate the number of days between each DD2 and DD1 
 n = n()) %>% 
 group_by(DD2,Type) %>% #because your operations are performed by each Type by DD2
 summarise(med  = median(diff_days),# calculates the median
           sum = sum(Price)) # and the sum

# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   DD2 [?]
  DD2        Type    med   sum
  <date>     <chr> <dbl> <int>
1 2017-12-30 2      19.0 30000
2 2017-12-30 3      19.0 60000
3 2018-01-20 2      14.0 25000
4 2018-01-25 3      19.5 25000
5 2018-01-27 3      23.0 50000
```

Now find the first day with a value in Price

```
 datematch <- dat %>% group_by(Type,month = floor_date(DD2, "month")) %>%
      arrange(Type, desc(DD2)) %>%
      summarise(maxDate = max(DD2)) %>% 
      select(Type, maxDate)
```

now create helper data frames for merging. dummy_dates will contain the last day with a value and the previous two days, for both types (low and high), all_dates will contain... well, all dates

```
list1 <- split(datematch$maxDate, datematch$Type)
list_type2 <- do.call('c',lapply(list1[['2']], function(x) seq(as.Date(x)-2, as.Date(x), by="days")))
list_type3 <- do.call('c',lapply(list1[['3']], function(x) seq(as.Date(x)-2, as.Date(x), by="days")))

dd_2 <- data.frame (DD2 = list_type2, Type = as.character(rep('2', length(list_type2))), stringsAsFactors = F)
dd_3 <- data.frame (DD2 = list_type3, Type = as.character(rep('3', length(list_type3))), stringsAsFactors = F)
dummy_date = rbind(dd_2, dd_3)
seq_date <- seq(as.Date('2017-12-01'),as.Date('2018-01-31'), by = 'days')
all_dates <- data.frame (DD2 = rep(seq_date,2), Type = as.character(rep(c('2','3'),each = length(seq_date))),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

now we can join your data frame with all days, so that every single day in the month gets a row

```
all_dates <- left_join(dd_date, dat_summary, by = c('DD2', 'Type'))
```

and we can filter this result with dummy_date, which (as we remember) contains only the required days before the last day with data

```
df1<-  left_join(dummy_date, all_dates,  by = c('DD2', 'Type')) %>% arrange(Type, desc(DD2))

df1
       DD2 Type  med   sum
1  2018-01-20    2 14.0 25000
2  2018-01-19    2   NA    NA
3  2018-01-18    2   NA    NA
4  2017-12-30    2 19.0 30000
5  2017-12-29    2   NA    NA
6  2017-12-28    2   NA    NA
7  2018-01-27    3 23.0 50000
8  2018-01-26    3   NA    NA
9  2018-01-25    3 19.5 25000
10 2017-12-30    3 19.0 60000
11 2017-12-29    3   NA    NA
12 2017-12-28    3   NA    NA
```

Sorry that 'type' is not correctly put as low and high, had problems to read your data. I hope that this helps somewhat

**edit**
added suggestion for a way to get to DF2

```
df1 %>% group_by(Type, month = floor_date(DD2, 'month')) %>% 
  summarise(sum = sum(sum, na.rm = T),
            n = max (n1, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  unite(sum.n, c('sum','n')) %>% 
  spread(Type, sum.n) %>%
  rename(low = '3', high = '2') %>%
  separate(high, c('high','n_high')) %>% 
  separate(low, c('low','n_low')) %>%
  mutate(dummy_low = as.integer(c(NA, low[1:length(low)-1])),
         dummy_high = as.integer(c(NA, high[1:length(high)-1])),
         low = as.integer(low), 
         high = as.integer(high))%>% 
    mutate(perc_low = 100*(low-dummy_low)/dummy_low)

# A tibble: 2 x 8
  month       high n_high   low n_low dummy_low dummy_high perc_low
  <date>     <int> <chr>  <int> <chr>     <int>      <int>    <dbl>
1 2017-12-01 30000 1      60000 1            NA         NA     NA  
2 2018-01-01 25000 1      75000 3         60000      30000     25.0
```

It's up to you to add the remaining columns for 'high' and the count. I am sure that the solution is not the most elegant one but it should work. DF2 has now only two months, but this is because you have provided only 2 months in your example. It should work with any number of months, and you can then filter the last three months.

Comment: I have already took difference and count by this approach in separate dataframe but my main problem is to daily create three rows in descending order from `DD2` and keeping the logic that if for some date row is not available than also show that date in `DF1` but value should be '0' and same for the `DF2` to took data of last three month as per data book and calculating the `%` increase or decrease.

Comment: Thanks for your support here..:)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to get the last day with data and the preceding two days, per month? Because if you want the last 3 days per month, you sometimes won't get data at all

Comment: Yes....For example if i run code for yesterday and ifs 27/01/2018 than i want data for 27/01/2018, 26/01/2018 & 25/01/2018 and same for month since its   January'2018 than Jan-18, Dec-18 & Nov-18. As you can see that i don't have rows for 26/01/2018 in initial dataframe but i also want a row in `DF1` for that date but values will be 0.

Comment: sorry. for clarification. What do you mean with 'take Median as per nrow' =  did you rather mean the mean ... (no pun intended;)

Comment: Taking sum of `DD2`-`DD1` differnce for particular Date or Month for particular `Type` and taking median instead of Average.

Comment: Sorry but i'm not able to convert the above code in dataframe, the output showing in R console.

Comment: puh, worked a lot on this now and learned a lot (good thing to try to answer other's questions... ;) I will edit the answer now. Not sure if it really helps though, is a bit convoluted.

Comment: Thanks....i'm glad that it really helped you to learn something new....:)

Comment: Thanks a lot...can we also have the exact `DF1` and `DF2` from this data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165497/discussion-between-tjebo-and-rahul-shah).